# Turn visual studio project testfixtures into nunit dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, nunit

I have a visual studio project. I later added a .cs file for testing and have added the appropriate 'using' statements and [Test] and [Testfixture] attributes. When I open the nunit gui application, however, it only accepts .dll, .exe, and .nunit files. I was wondering what exact steps I need to take to execute the tests I wrote. Is it possible to do so directly in visual studio?

Comment: Take the dll into which you compiled the mentioned .cs files.

Comment: I tried to compile the .cs file into a dll, with the command csc /target:library /out:Tests.dll Tests.cs, but I got the error message 'csc' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: Regarding the 'unrecognized command , you need to add the Microsoft.net framework folder to your path

Comment: I opened the vs command window and have it installed. But when I ran the compile command, the words 'Nunit', 'Test', and 'TestFixture' were not recognized. How do I compile so that these features are included? Better yet, how do I compile so that it understands selenium webdriver as well?

Answer (score 1):

You should add the NUnit dll as a reference on your project. 
JetBrains' Resharper is able to run the tests inside Visual Studio. Read more about Resharpers  unittesting [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/unit_testing.html). JetBrains has also developed a line coverage tool: dotCover.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) is the best solution.

[Test Driven .Net](http://www.testdriven.net/download_release.aspx?LicenceType=Personal) is the best free solution I know of.

[Visual Studio 11](http://www.peterprovost.org/blog/post/Whats-New-in-Visual-Studio-11-Beta-Unit-Testing.aspx) will finally allow for 3rd part testing framework plugins.